# How do I change my username on Trello after I set up my account with my Google account?

Tags: google, trello, account-management, username

I set up my Trello account by using the "Log In With Google Account" option.  That created a username for me.

I don't like that username.

Can it be changed?  If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Visit https://trello.com/your/account
2. Click **Change Name, Initials, or Bio**
   [image: Change Name, Initials, or Bio]
3. Edit your username
4. Click **Save**

Answer (score 2):

So, I had the same problem as Danny.

I used my Google login to create a Trello account, and didn't appreciate the 1 tacked onto the end of my username.

Surprisingly, the following worked....

Note that I had 2 accounts, was an invited member of a private board (tied to the "wrong" username) and still got it ALL sorted out to my liking. Goldilocks would be happy.

First, I created my account. I noticed that I was able to access the private board I had been invited to. Then I noticed that my username was 1. Yuck. I want to be me, not me1.

Second, in another browser (not sharing cookies where my me1 account was) I created a new account using an email, and got the correct username.
Correct Username means...  (not )

Now, I am in that account... and it doesn't have access to the private board. Ok, as me1 I add me to the private board. Doh! That doesn't work. That email is not the email the invite was sent to.

It's at this point I notice, in the profile for me1, that I could have EDITED the username. I try that "now" and I am told that username "me" is in use. So I'm still "logged in" to two accounts, me1 and the new account me.

So, I'm screwed. Right? With most systems I would be. I'm still surprised that THIS worked....

1. Delete account me1 (that has access to the private board). Yes, permanently delete my account. Get an email for that, click the link, confirm a couple times. Account deleted very permanently.
2. Go back to account me. Go to my profile, and add credentials. The email associated with account me1 just seconds ago... Is now added to my account me. (Trello released it, and allowed it to be added to a different account. Wow. Nice!) It's the secondary email. Amazingly, there's a link to set it as the PRIMARY email on the account.

Now I have what I wanted in the first place - account me =  and the email which was invited to the private board is the primary email on the account.

Now the critical question.

3. Does my "correct" me account have access to the board I was invited to?

Yes...

I think things just worked at that point. I (once again) had access to the private board without doing anything further. I don't think I had to go back to the invite email. Maybe I did. Point being, it worked.

Even more amazed...

I now go through the 'sign up with name and email' again, and it... again assigns me account name me1. 1 Amazing. me1 wasn't permanently reserved. In most systems, even though I deleted that account, the username would be reserved and impossible to use ever again. Here, that's not the case.

Deleting a trello account releases the email associated with it to be added to another trello account, and it further releases the username to be used again. (Which means that the username can be used for creating a new account, or someone could claim my discarded username using the account rename feature.)

Comment: You, my friend, are a life saver! It was driving me NUTS!